# How to get the center point of a Face or a PlanarFace element in Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm doing a Revit Macro to get the center point of a part (floor part) to check if it is inside a room or a space.
I couldn't get much of the `BoundingBox` object which is giving me a point outside the part, so I tried to use the `Geometry` element internal faces getting the mesh vertices but I'm stuck calculating the mid point.
I'm using a rather naive algorithm shown in the snippet below, but it's giving me false results as it seems to be affected by the initial default of min/max variables. 
Any suggestions?

PS: DebugTools is a custom helper class of my own.

```
public void ZoneDetect()
{
    Document doc = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

    using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc,"Set Rooms By Region"))
    {
        t.Start();

        FilteredElementCollector fec = 
            new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
                .OfClass(typeof(Part))
                .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Parts)
                .Cast<Part>();

        foreach (Part p in fec)
        {


            Options op = new Options();
            op.View=doc.ActiveView;
            op.ComputeReferences=true;

            GeometryElement gm=p.get_Geometry(op);
            Solid so = gm.First() as Solid;
            PlanarFace fc=so.Faces.get_Item(0) as PlanarFace;

            foreach (PlanarFace f in so.Faces)
            {
                if (f.Normal == new XYZ(0,0,-1))  fc=f;
            }
            XYZ max = new XYZ();
            XYZ min = new XYZ();

            int no = 0;
            foreach (XYZ vx in fc.Triangulate().Vertices) 
            {
                // Just for debugging
                DebugTools.DrawModelTick(vx,doc,"Max");
                doc.Regenerate();
                TaskDialog.Show("Point:"+no.ToString(),vx.ToString());
                no++;

                //Comparing points
                if (vx.X>max.X) max=new XYZ (vx.X,max.Y,0);
                if (vx.Y>max.Y) max=new XYZ (max.X,vx.Y,0);
                if (vx.X<min.X) min=new XYZ (vx.X,min.Y,0);
                if (vx.Y<min.Y) min=new XYZ (min.X,vx.Y,0);
            }

            XYZ mid = new XYZ(max.X-min.X,max.Y-min.Y,0);

            DebugTools.DrawModelTick(mid,doc,"Mid");
            DebugTools.DrawModelTick(max,doc,"Max");
            DebugTools.DrawModelTick(min,doc,"Min");
        }

        t.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for the center of gravity of a polygon. An algorithm for that can be found here: [Center of gravity of a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271583/center-of-gravity-of-a-polygon)

Once you have a `Face` object, you can enumerate its edges to receive a list of vertex points. Use the longest of the `EdgeLoops` in the face. Collect all the points and make sure that they are in the right order (the start and end points of the edges might need to be swapped).

Comment: That said, there are still going to be hypothetical cases where the center of gravity is not on the floor itself. In some cases you're better off doing a grid of points and determine if a point is inside the face or not.

Answer (score 0):

Daren & Matt thanks a lot for your answers,
Since I'm dealing with rather simple shapes ( mainly rectangles ) I just needed to get a point roughly near the center to test whether it is inside a room, my problem was with the naive algorithm I was using which turned out to be wrong.
I corrected it as follows:

```
XYZ midSum = Max + Min;
XYZ mid = new XYZ(midSum.X/2 , midSum.Y/2,0);
```

I will look into refining it using the link you've provided, but as for now I will get into finishing my task in hand.

Many thanks